# suspend function testing with spock

Tags: kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines, spock, suspend

I have a simple function in kotlin like that :

```
suspend fun createTicket(@Valid request: CreateTicketRequest, authentication: Authentication): HttpResponse<Any> {
    request.customerId = "customerId"
    logger().info("Receive by the client $request")
    return HttpResponse.created(service.create(request))
}
```

I've already Mock the request and the authentication.

So, I call it on Spock:

```
def 'It should create a ticket with success'() {
    given:
    def request = createRequest(
            TICKET_ID,
            TICKET_NAME,
            TICKET_PHONE,
            TICKET_CPF,
            TICKET_EMAIL,
            TICKET_COMMENT,
            TICKET_SUBJECT,
            TICKET_TAG
    )


    when:
    response = controller.createTicket(
            request,
            authentication
    )

    then:
    response != null

}
```

I'm getting the following error :
Suspend function 'create' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function.

Can anyone help me with this question ?

Best regards

Comment: Have a look at [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test)

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't pay attention enough, you're calling it from Groovy. Then maybe the workaround in this issue could help: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1812

Comment: You could also probably write a helper class in kotlin that uses `kotlinx-coroutines-test` and is callable from Java/Groovy to bridge between both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Solved I created a Kotlin class code

```
class CallCreateTicket {

    private lateinit var response: HttpResponse<Any>

    private fun createTicket(
        request: CreateTicketRequest,
        authenticator: Authenticator,
        controller: TicketController,
    ): HttpResponse<Any> {
        runBlocking {
            response = controller.createTicket(request, authenticator)
        }
        return response
    }

}
```

and I called it on groovy ...

```
    @Mockable(TicketCreateServiceImpl)
class TicketControllerTest extends Specification {

    def mockUtil = new MockUtil()
    def service = Mock(TicketCreateServiceImpl)
    def authenticator = Mock(Authenticator)
    def response = Mock(HttpResponse)

    def controller = new TicketController(service)

    def callCreateTicket = new CallCreateTicket()

    def 'check if all instances are mocked'() {

        mockUtil.isMock(authentication)
        mockUtil.isMock(service)

    }

    def 'It should call the index function and return a valid String'() {

        when:
        response = controller.index()

        then:
        response == INDEX_RETURN
    }

    def 'It should call the index function and return a invalid String'() {

        when:
        response = controller.index()

        then:
        response != INVALID_INDEX_RETURN
    }

    def 'It should create a ticket with success'() {
        given:
        def request = createRequest(
                TICKET_ID,
                TICKET_NAME,
                TICKET_PHONE,
                TICKET_CPF,
                TICKET_EMAIL,
                TICKET_COMMENT,
                TICKET_SUBJECT,
                TICKET_TAG
        )


        when:
        response = callCreateTicket.createTicket(
                request,
                authenticator,
                controller
        )

        then:
        response.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)

    }

}
```